# Stop 'Battery 100% Charged' notifications

Tags: battery, notifications, charging

I have a MBP 2018. After upgrading to Catalina, when unattended with the power adapter connected, after a while the machine will start chiming every ten seconds and displaying a '100% Charged' message on the screen.

It's driving me nuts. How can I stop it?

Weirdly, I can't find any references to this online; there are even some references to people *wanting* such a notification. It's a new installation, so I don't think there's any custom software doing this. Is this a new Catalina feature?

Comment: I was going over the release notes for Catalina 10.15.5 and.6 and can't find anything about battery full notifications.  I only know of 3rd party apps that do this.  Can you confirm by booting into Safe Mode (hold `Shift` while booting). If it stops, something is being loaded at boot that causes it.

Comment: I've not seen any such notifications, either.

Comment: I tried safe mode, and it still happens, but I didn't get any notifications that safe mode has been entered, so maybe that didn't work? I do notice that I can provoke the message by unplugging and reinserting the USB-C cable.

Comment: There's no notification for entering Safe Mode.  So, in Safe Mode, it will send a "Full Battery Notification" when you unplug/plug the charger?  Three things...can you verify your macOS version (click Apple logo → About this Mac) and can you try creating another user and see if it happens there.  Also check to see if it happens when **not** logged in (don't sign in and remove/reinsert the charger).  Does it give you the audible alert?

Comment: One last thing... use @name (@Allan for me) to ping users in comments so we get notified when you respond.

Comment: @Allan Sorry for the delay --- I had some trouble duplicating it. OS: 10.15.7. Logged out: yes, still happens. I am suspecting now that the USB C power supply could be turning itself off and on, possibly in response to the machine putting itself into an ultra-low power state? This would explain why I was having trouble duplicating it; if the battery runs down a little, then on reconnection it would charge, drawing power from the power supply. I'll try with a different one.

Comment: That's not how a USB-C power supply works.  The power supply interacts with a USB mux chip on the logic board. The two negotiate how much power is delivered - all of it is done outside and independent of the operating system.  I have checked several Macs and I couldn't find any that had a "battery full alert" setting.

Comment: The alert is happening to me while powering via thunderbolt monitor. Super obnoxious. Saw another post elsewhere where apple techs implicated the power supply. @allan I think david might be right.

Comment: This is still happening on macOS Ventura, I have seen it on both M1 and M3 chips - alert is 100% Charged Battery Icon - lasts a couple of minutes and is very annoying