# MacBook turns external monitor on when fully charged

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, usb, charging

My MacBook Air M2 is connected with a USB-C cable to an external display (Samsung S27H850QFU).
When I leave my desk without shutting the display down, the MacBook will show the 'x%' notification on the lock screen after like 20 minutes of inactivity.

The problem here is that this notification turns both the internal and external display on and this triggers the monitor to charge the MacBook again for like 20 seconds. After 20 seconds, both displays go into power save mode, then the 'x%' notification appears again after 15 seconds.

This is really annoying because the monitor goes dark, then shows the MacBook screen for a few seconds (the x% charged notification), then goes dark again and so on. Also the "now charging"-sound of macOS plays every time.

[Video of this bug](https://youtu.be/GEFja2HQawI)

The only way to stop this behavior is by turning the display off manually.

I initially thought it was a problem with the monitor because it has to be turned on manually and does not turn on when the MacBook starts, but the problem did not appear with a 2019 MacBook Pro.

I'm pretty clueless as to why this happens so help is appreciated!

Comment: I doubt this is the cause, but is `System Settings -> Notifications -> Allow notifications when the display is sleeping` on by chance? If so, could you turn it off and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help.

Comment: [This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/403086/stop-battery-100-charged-notifications) implies that it might be the charger; do you have another charger you could try?