# MacBook frequently stops charging briefly when battery at 100%

Tags: battery, charging

Once my laptop battery reaches 100%, when unattended, every 5 to 30 minutes, the MagSafe 3 cable light briefly turns off, turns back on, the "100% Charged" message will show on the screen, and the computer will chime.  (Similar to this other [unanswered post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/403086/stop-battery-100-charged-notifications)).  This becomes fairly annoying, and I'm also concerned it will be bad for my battery.

I have a 2023 MacBook Pro M2 Max, and using the charger in the box.  I did a fresh install when I got it.

When troubleshooting:

1. Happens on multiple different outlets
2. This happened both on Ventura and when I upgraded to Sonoma
3. Brought the laptop to an Apple Store and they found no issues when running diagnostics
4. Apple Store cleaned the MagSafe connection
5. Apple Store performed a Firmware Revive

I suspect there may be some software or setting triggering this behavior.  I was trying to find some relevant logs and found these by typing `pmset -g log`.  I'm not sure if these are normal or point to anything.

```
2023-11-19 11:55:30 -0600 Wake Requests         
[process=PowerUIAgent request=Maintenance deltaSecs=86416 wakeAt=2023-11-20 11:55:45 info="com.apple.obc"]
[process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=908 wakeAt=2023-11-19 12:10:38 info="com.apple.dasd:501:com.apple.intelligenceplatform.IntelligencePlatformCore.ViewEvery21Minutes"]
[process=dasd request=TimerPlugin deltaSecs=1035 wakeAt=2023-11-19 12:12:45 info="com.apple.dasd:501:com.apple.ScreenTimeAgent.activity.clean-up-expired-store-items"]
[process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=5382 wakeAt=2023-11-19 13:25:12 info="DHCP lease renewal"]
[process=powerd request=CSPNEvaluation deltaSecs=7216 wakeAt=2023-11-19 13:55:46]
[*process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=448 wakeAt=2023-11-19 12:02:58 info="com.apple.alarm.user-invisible-keysync.retry,1466"]           
2023-11-19 11:55:30 -0600 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [com.apple.bluetooth.sleep is slow(1541 ms)]           
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 Assertions            PID 454(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000086fd [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 Assertions            PID 454(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000086fd [System: No Assertions]          
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 Assertions            PID 319(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "PM configd - Wait for Device enumeration" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000086fe [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 com.apple.sleepservices.sessionStarted    SleepService: window begins with cap time=180 secs                                    
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNP] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan/ Using AC (Charge:100%) 2 secs    
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 WakeDetails           
DriverReason:SMC.OutboxNotEmpty - DriverDetails:                           
DriverReason:smc.70070000 - DriverDetails:                                 
DriverReason:wifibt - DriverDetails:                                       
DriverReason:wlan - DriverDetails:                                         
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0                                        238           
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.111 sec                                                                   
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: 
[AppleBCMWLANCore driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(116 ms)] 
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: 
[AppleCS42L84Audio driver is slow(msg: DidChangeState to 1)(77 ms)]
[Codec Output driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 1)(77 ms)]
[RTBuddy(ANS2) driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(101 ms)] [AppleMultiFunctionManager driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(116 ms)]
[AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(113 ms)]           
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 Assertions            PID 319(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008700 [System: PushSrvc SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 Assertions            PID 400(PowerUIAgent) Created MaintenanceWake "com.apple.obc" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008705 [System: PushSrvc SRPrevSleep IPushSrvc kCPU]          
2023-11-19 11:55:31 -0600 Assertions            PID 400(PowerUIAgent) Released MaintenanceWake "com.apple.obc" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008705 [System: PushSrvc SRPrevSleep IPushSrvc kCPU]          
2023-11-19 11:55:32 -0600 Assertions            Summary- [System: PushSrvc SRPrevSleep kCPU] Using Batt(Charge: 100)          
2023-11-19 11:55:32 -0600 Assertions            PID 319(powerd) CapExpired ApplePushServiceTask "Powerd - Wait for client pushService assertions" 00:00:01  id:0x0xa000086ff [System: PushSrvc SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-11-19 11:55:32 -0600 com.apple.sleepservices.sessionTerminated SleepService: window has terminated.                                                  
2023-11-19 11:55:33 -0600 Assertions            Summary- [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU] Using AC(Charge: 100)          
2023-11-19 11:55:33 -0600 Assertions            PID 1276(PowerChime) Created DisplayWake "com.apple.chimeOnAttach" 00:00:00  id:0x0xe00008706 [System: SRPrevSleep DispWake kCPU]          
2023-11-19 11:55:33 -0600 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Deep Idle [CDNVAP] : due to Notification Using AC (Charge:100%) 4 secs
```

Near the end of the logs you can see `Using Batt(Charge: 100)` followed by `Using AC(Charge: 100)` just a second later, and a message about the power chime.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 The answer still may help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up getting my [140W charger](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MLYU3AM/A/140w-usb-c-power-adapter) replaced by Apple, and no longer seeing this issue.